# How to add a new variable to a viewhelper (Typo3 9)

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-9.x

I created my own viewhelper for getting all Information of an Image with the UID.
I get all the Information, if I print the array in the viewhelper, but im not able to create a new Fluid variable with all these information, to work with in the Template.

I tried to create the new variable with:

```
$this->view->assign('sliderItems', $sliderItems);
```

But I receive „Call to a member function assign() on null“.

I render the Image with:

```
public function render() {
    /* MY RENDER STUFF */
```

And then I will submit the array with:

```
    $this->view->assign('sliderItems', $sliderItems);
}
```

How can I solve this, to get an access with fluid?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the templateVariableContainer for that:

```
$this->templateVariableContainer->add('key', 'value');
```

If you use the viewhelper in a loop, you'll have to remove the variable after render:

```
$this->templateVariableContainer->add('key', 'value');
$output = $this->renderChildren();
$this->templateVariableContainer->remove('key');
return $output;
```

If you use your viewhelper in your template, the variable will be available in your fluid template.

```
<vendor:viewhelper>
{key}
</vendor:viewhelper>
```